# How to like, unlike and comment on Facebook using restfb?

Tags: java, restfb

I am newbie to Java and restfb. I am trying to like, unlike and comment on a user and a page post, But cannot find much information in the docs of restfb. I am done with all the oauth process and can even pull the post.

Answer (score 7):

Like a post:

```
DefaultFacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(access_token);
client.publish(post.getId()+"/likes", Boolean.class);
```

Unlike a post:

```
DefaultFacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(access_token);
post.getLikes();
// retrieve a specific like, then
client.delete(like);
```

Comment on a post:

```
DefaultFacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(access_token);
client.publish(post.getId()+"/comments", String.class, Parameter.with("message", "Your comment here"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Can u tell me something about unline and comment.